# Are Drupal hooks an implementation of event -handling in Java?

Tags: java, drupal, event-handling

What is your opinion?
Are Drupal hooks an implementation of event -handling in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they basically are similar to the Observer pattern.

The main difference is that hooks are called based on a naming convention and not explicit registering.

See http://drupal.org/node/547518 for more information.

Comment: Actually are hooks the same as "Listeners" in Java?

Comment: Well, yes, "a" hook, for example hook_menu() would be something like a Listener interface that defines the API and name of the hook. A module called "yourmodule" could then create a function named "yourmodule_menu" and Drupal would automatically discover that as a implementation of that Listener.